# Android: Execute enqueue first Retrofit

Tags: java, android, response, retrofit2

I have some troubles trying to execute this code:

```
        @Override
    public void loginProcessGoogle(User googleUser) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .callbackExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);
        User user = new User();

        String email =  googleUser.getEmail() == null ? "" : googleUser.getEmail();

        String name = googleUser.getName();
        String googleId = googleUser.getProvider_id();

        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setName(name);
        user.setProvider_id(googleId);
        user.setProvider_name(User.provider_name_google);
        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setUser(user);
        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.socialAuthenticate(request);

        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

                ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                Snackbar.make(getView(), resp.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);
                    editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL,resp.getUser().getEmail());
                    editor.putString(Constants.NAME,resp.getUser().getName());
                    editor.putString(Constants.ID,resp.getUser().getId());
                    editor.apply();
                    goToProfile();
                }
                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"failed");
                Snackbar.make(getView(), t.getLocalizedMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        String testString= "Hello";
    }
```

When im debuggin this code, i put a breakpoint for example in **user.setEmail(email);**,it enters, also with another before the response.enqueue callback, when im trying to put a breakpoint inside onResponse method, it goes immediately to the string variable in the bottom (**testString**)
What is the best way to enter first into the **response.enqueue** before the string variable in the bottom, for example in **ServerResponse resp = response.body();**?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, because the enqueue method run in another thread with the thread you setEmail, untill retrofit receive the result it execute onResponse method.
Yo can use excute method instead enque. See here for more details https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests.